# JPA repository fail with good name of property and works with wrong name

Tags: spring, jpa, repository

I have a class with property named isChecked with is boolean type. In Jpa repository I wrote a method to find all rows which has isChecked = false;

```
public interface ReservationReminderRepository extends JpaRepository<ReservationReminder, Integer> {
ReservationReminder findByReservationReminderId(Integer id);

//@Query("select r from ReservationReminder r where r.isChecked = :checked")
List<ReservationReminder> findByChecked(boolean checked);


}
```

While I tried to call a method findByChecked() in Jpa reporistory everything works, but when I tried to run a method with the proper named of property - as it is in jpa doc findByIsChecked() I got strange fails:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [isChecked] on this ManagedType [com.carwash.domains.ReservationReminder]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:128)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:113)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:566)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.getTypedPath(JpaQueryCreator.java:334)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:277)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:182)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:109)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:49)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:118)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:241)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
... 104 more
```

Can anyone tell me why I received that kind of fail? How the method name would looks like when I'd like to check with property checkedDate?

```
package com.carwash.domains;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

/**
* Created by mbi on 01.03.2017.
*/
@Entity
public class ReservationReminder {
private int reservationReminderId;
private Reservation reservation;
private boolean isChecked;
private Date checkedDate;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getReservationReminderId() {
    return reservationReminderId;
}

public void setReservationReminderId(int reservationReminderId) {
    this.reservationReminderId = reservationReminderId;
}

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "reservationReminder")
public Reservation getReservation() {
    return reservation;
}

public void setReservation(Reservation reservation) {
    this.reservation = reservation;
}

public boolean getChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}

public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
    isChecked = checked;
}

public Date getCheckedDate() {
    return checkedDate;
}

public void setCheckedDate(Date checkedDate) {
    this.checkedDate = checkedDate;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ReservationReminder{" +
            "reviewId=" + reservationReminderId +
            ", isChecked=" + isChecked +
            ", checkedDate=" + checkedDate +
            '}';
}

public ReservationReminder() {
}

public ReservationReminder(Boolean isChecked, Date checkedDate) {
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
    this.checkedDate = checkedDate;
}

public ReservationReminder(int reservationReminderId, Reservation reservation, boolean isChecked, Date checkedDate) {
    this.reservationReminderId = reservationReminderId;
    this.reservation = reservation;
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
    this.checkedDate = checkedDate;
}
}
```

Comment: As your annotations are on the methods your property is named `checked` and not `isChecked`. If the annotations would be on the fields then it would be `isChecked`. So it acually works as JPA should work. Setting the annotations on the methods switches on the `AccessType.PROPERTY` instead of the default `AccessType.FIELD`.

Comment: You mean something like that:
`@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class ReservationReminder`

Comment: You cannot mix field and property access... It is either FIELD or PROPERTY but not both. Just move your annotations to the fields instead of the getters.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. Please paste an egxmaple how it should looks like

Comment: The fact that your annotations are on the properties and NOT the fields automatically enables `AccesType.PROPERTY`... As stated just move the annotations to the fields instead of the properties (i.e the getters/setters!).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is related to the naming of that property.

As you are telling Spring to look for `findByChecked` and the property name is `isChecked`.

You can try to use `findByIsChecked` and change the getter to `isChecked`.

But actually i would change the property to `checked`, getter to `isChecked` and leave the jpa query method as it is.